# How can I efficiently convert a scipy sparse matrix into a sympy sparse matrix?

Tags: scipy, sparse-matrix, sympy

I have a matrix A with the following properties.

```
<1047x1047 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 888344 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

A has this content.

```
array([[ 1.00000000e+00, -5.85786642e-17, -3.97082034e-17, ...,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 6.82195979e-17,  1.00000000e+00, -4.11166786e-17, ...,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [-4.98202332e-17,  1.13957868e-17,  1.00000000e+00, ...,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       ...,
       [ 4.56847824e-15,  1.32261454e-14, -7.22890998e-15, ...,
         1.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [-9.11597396e-15, -2.28796167e-14,  1.26624823e-14, ...,
         0.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 1.80765584e-14,  1.93779820e-14, -1.36520100e-14, ...,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00]])
```

Now I'm trying to create a **sympy** sparse matrix from this scipy sparse matrix.

```
from sympy.matrices import SparseMatrix
A = SparseMatrix(A)
```

But I get this error message.

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

I am confused because this matrix has no logical entries.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What inputs does the sympy function accept?  Doss it mention acipy sparse at all?

Answer (score 3):

### The Error

When you get an error that you don't understand, take a bit of time to look at the traceback. Or at least show it to us!

```
In [288]: M = sparse.random(5,5,.2, 'csr')                                                           

In [289]: M                                                                                          
Out[289]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [290]: print(M)                                                                                   
  (1, 1)    0.17737340878962138
  (2, 2)    0.12362174819457106
  (2, 3)    0.24324155883057885
  (3, 0)    0.7666429046432961
  (3, 4)    0.21848551209470246

In [291]: SparseMatrix(M)                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-291-cca56ea35868> in <module>
----> 1 SparseMatrix(M)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sympy/matrices/sparse.py in __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    206             else:
    207                 # handle full matrix forms with _handle_creation_inputs
--> 208                 r, c, _list = Matrix._handle_creation_inputs(*args)
    209                 self.rows = r
    210                 self.cols = c

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sympy/matrices/matrices.py in _handle_creation_inputs(cls, *args, **kwargs)
   1070                             if 0 in row.shape:
   1071                                 continue
-> 1072                         elif not row:
   1073                             continue
   1074 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in __bool__(self)
    281             return self.nnz != 0
    282         else:
--> 283             raise ValueError("The truth value of an array with more than one "
    284                              "element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().")
    285     __nonzero__ = __bool__

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

A full understanding requires reading the `sympy` code, but a cursory look indicates that it's trying to handle your input as "full matrix", and looks at rows.  The error isn't the result of you doing logical operations on the entries, but that `sympy` is doing a logical test on your sparse matrix.  It's trying to check if the row is empty (so it can skip it).

`SparseMatrix` docs may not be the clearest, but most examples either show a dict of points, or a flat array of ALL values plus shape, or a ragged list of lists.  I suspect it's trying to treat your matrix that way, looking at it row by row.

But the row of `M` is itself a sparse matrix:

```
In [295]: [row for row in M]                                                                         
Out[295]: 
[<1x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
...]
```

And trying to check if that row is empty `not row` produces this error:

```
In [296]: not [row for row in M][0]                                                                  
...
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

So clearly `SparseMatrix` cannot handle a `scipy.sparse` matrix as is (at least not in the `csr` or `csc` format, and probably not the others.  Plus `scipy.sparse` is not mentioned anywhere in the `SparseMatrix` docs!

### from dense array

Converting the sparse matrix to its dense equivalent does work:

```
In [297]: M.A                                                                                        
Out[297]: 
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.17737341, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.12362175, 0.24324156, 0.        ],
       [0.7666429 , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.21848551],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]])

In [298]: SparseMatrix(M.A)                                                                          
Out[298]: 
⎡        0                  0                  0                  0                  0        ⎤
...⎦
```

Or a list of lists:

```
 SparseMatrix(M.A.tolist())
```

### from dict

The `dok` format stores a sparse matrix as a `dict`, which then can be

```
In [305]: dict(M.todok())                                                                            
Out[305]: 
{(3, 0): 0.7666429046432961,
 (1, 1): 0.17737340878962138,
 (2, 2): 0.12362174819457106,
 (2, 3): 0.24324155883057885,
 (3, 4): 0.21848551209470246}
```

Which works fine as an input:

```
SparseMatrix(5,5,dict(M.todok()))
```

I don't know what's most efficient.  Generally when working with `sympy` we (or at least I) don't worry about efficiency.  Just get it to work is enough.  Efficiency is more relevant in `numpy/scipy` where arrays can be large, and using the fast compiled numpy methods makes a big difference in speed.

Finally - `numpy` and `sympy` are not integrated.  That applies also to the sparse versions.  `sympy` is built on Python, not `numpy`.  So inputs in the form of lists and dicts makes most sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
from sympy.matrices import SparseMatrix
import scipy.sparse as sps

A = sps.random(100, 10, format="dok")
B = SparseMatrix(100, 10, dict(A.items()))
```

From the perspective of someone who likes efficient memory structures this is like staring into the abyss. But it will work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified version of your error.

```
from scipy import sparse
row = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2])
col = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
A = sparse.csc_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3, 3))
```

So `A` is a sparse matrix with 6 elements:

```
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

Calling `SparseMatrix()` on it returns the same kind of error that you have. You might like to convert `A` to numpy array first:

```
>>> SparseMatrix(A.todense())
Matrix([
[1, 0, 2],
[0, 0, 3],
[4, 5, 6]])
```